# ItemUpdating called twice after ItemAdded in event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've created an event receiver to handle the ItemAdded and ItemUpdating events on a document library in SharePoint 2010.

I've encountered a problem where when I add a document to the library (e.g. by saving it back from Word) the ItemAdded method is correctly called however this is then followed by two calls to ItemUpdating.  I have removed all code from my handlers to ensure that it's not something I'm doing inside that is causing the problem.  They literally look like:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
}

public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Here is my elements.xml file for the event receiver:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>DocumentsEventReceiverItemUpdating</Name>
        <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.Namespace.DocumentsEventReceiver</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
      </Receiver>
      <Receiver>
        <Name>DocumentsEventReceiverItemAdded</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.Namespace.DocumentsEventReceiver</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is that In `Document library` event handlers during `Item Updating` also checking that `Document` is it in **Check In** mode or **Check Out**. That's why it is called twice.

You should put your code in

```
 public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {  
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null && properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
     {
       //do stuff
     }
  }
```

For further details ***[Here](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=1424)*** is good article for describe whole situation of the `Document's` Events.

Comment: My if statement isn't exactly the same as yours but I can use the field you mentioned.  vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby in the before and after properties is always null during my actual updates so I can just check that.  When ItemUpdating is called after ItemAdded both are populated with my username

Comment: Yes thanks!  The ItemUpdating still fires but the if statement lets me determine whether or not to actually run my code

Comment: yes..that point of me!! its always fire twice according my knowledge. we never prevent its but we stop run code in couple of times using this statements.

Comment: I have same problem as yours, can you please tell me what is the statement you are using. properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"]  and properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] are always null and i'm unable to know if ItemUpdated is fired alone or after adding a file.